# How to limit outgoing traffic per IP Address using Linux TC

Tags: linux, networking, tc

I want to limit outgoing traffic per IP address. For example I have a network interface eth0, having 1Gbps of bandwidth.

I want to limit the whole network interface to 1Mbps each destination IP Address.

For example 1Mbps for 192.168.1.1 and 1Mbps for 192.168.1.2

Currently I am using wondershaper using this command:

```
wondershaper eth0 1024[outbound traffic] 1024000[inbound traffic]
```

But this is limiting the whole network interface and there won't be seperated traffic for each IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You might need iptables' CLASSIFY. See 
http://www.fyzix.net/index.php?title=Traffic_shaping_with_tc_and_iptables